# Asp.Net Core 2,Entity Framework and Services. Weird Behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, hangfire

I'm adding a new method to a service that already works. This new method is used by a HangFire job. This is how I add it to the `Configure` method of the `Startup.cs`

```
// Create the daily tasks
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<ITaskService>(x => x.CreateRecurringTasks(), Cron.Daily(0));
```

And this is the constructor of the service. Note that I create the DB context in the start so I don't have transaction problems when using it inside a controller.

```
public TaskService(
    IMapper mapper,
    INotificationService notificationService,
    IConfiguration configuration
)
{

    var opts = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ProjectDbContext>();
    opts.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    _dbContext = new ProjectDbContext(opts.Options);

    _configuration = configuration;
    _mapper = mapper;
    _notificationService = notificationService;
}
```

My problem is that the method below won't add the row in the database.

```
void LogRepeatedTask(long copiedTaskId, long originalTaskId) {
    _dbContext.TaskRepeatLogs.Add(new Data.Models.TaskRepeatLog
    {
        CopiedTaskId = copiedTaskId,
        OriginalTaskId = originalTaskId,
        UtcDate = DateTime.UtcNow
    });
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

This is the model. As you can see it is pretty simple:

```
public class TaskRepeatLog
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long OriginalTaskId { get; set; }
    public long CopiedTaskId { get; set; }
    public DateTime UtcDate { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the DbSet in the `ProjectDbContext`:

```
public DbSet<TaskRepeatLog> TaskRepeatLogs { get; set; }
```

Everything seems pretty straightforward to me but I can't understand why the method is not working. Even the select on this DbSet seems not to work properly and I don't understand what I did wrong. Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure 'LogRepeatedTask' is hit at all? I don't see any reference in the code you've shown.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Yes it is. The method that uses it is gigantic and it is not relevant to the question. But yes, it is hit I saw it being hit on the debug.

Comment: Did you check the connectionstring? Since you are using a new instance, it may be looking at a different db.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg yes I did. This service is already used in many places and most of the methods work with the database. Even the new methods work. Only this method seems to be the problem, actually this new entity because I add entries to the DB manually and _dbContext.TaskRepeatLogs.First(), for example, won't return anything

Comment: You are using EF6? And the method never inserted a row, not in debug and not in production? Can you add a try-catch around it? Perhaps there is some underlying error that is causing this behaviour.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg ok, I'll try the Try-Catch, If I get the error I'll update the question or fix myself and then post here. I'm using Entity Framework Core 2. Tnx

Comment: @RuardvanElburg you were right. See my answer. Thanks for the hit!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The problem was that I was calling the `LogRepeatedTask` inside a loop and it was throwing an error saying that there was another transaction happening.

This is where I was calling the function. I just removed from there, added the Ids to a dictionary and I'm using from there.

```
    var tasks = _dbContext.Tasks
        .Include(i => i.RepeatConfig)
        .Where(p => p.RepeatTask && p.RepeatConfig != null && p.CopiedFromTaskId == null);

    if (tasks != null)
    {
        foreach (var task in tasks)
        {
            // I was calling the method here. 
        }
    }
```

So there was no weird behavior.